# An element $a$ in a monoid $A$ such that $a\cdot x=a$ for any $x\in A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, semigroups, monoid

Let $(A,\cdot)$ be a non-abelian monoid. I was just wondering if there is a name or terminology for an element $a\in A$ that satisfies one of the following propertes:

(1) For any $x\in A$, we have $x\cdot a= a$.

Or

(2) For any $x\in A$, we have $a\cdot x=a$.

Comment: (Left- or right-) absorbing element? If both conditions are satisfied, then, maybe, zero?

Comment: @Alexey If both (1) and (2) hold, then it should be zero. But, what if only one of them holds?

Comment: I've edited the comment.

Comment: Both suggestions seems to be correct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element: "...left zero, where one requires only that $z • s = z$, and right zero, where $s • z = z$."

Answer (score 0):

(1) is called a right zero, (2) is called a left zero.  I'm pretty sure there's no general term for both, but you can just say 'left or right zero'.